# How to auto-start an application after system boot up in Mac os

Tags: java, macos, autostart

Hi I have created a sample java swing application Mac os. Now I want whenever I will start my computer then my java application will start automatically.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: Not a programming related. Belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Launchd to start your application at the system level.  Here is an [example](http://milhousink.com/blog/2008/09/14/launchd-example-in-os-x-leopard-105/).

Comment: Could you please change the link? because it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in the account setting of your user profile, in the Startup items tab.

http://www.engadget.com/2004/07/20/how-to-make-programs-automatically-start-up-in-mac-os-x/